# Make a page on website accessible after logging in

Tags: c#, authentication

I need a code behind that i can use to make a page on a website accessible after authenticating it via logon,meaning i want it to be accessible when a specific user is logged in only.
Any one who can help me out.

(NB:am a leaner, still a newbie)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any database table that contains login credenentials

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [FAQ]

Comment: yes i do have it @Rajeev Kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then a very simple programm i write for u

```
 readonly SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VerbaLinksConString"].ToString());

 try
 {
    SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("Select txt_Password from table where txt_user_name = '"+txtUserName.Text+"' and txt_Pwd = '"+txtPassword.Text+"'",sqlCon);
   sqlCon.Open();
   SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   If(dr.Read())
   {
     Response.Redirect("HomePage.aspx");
   }
   else
   {
     Response.Write("Either userId or Password is wrong");
   }
   SqlCon.Close(); 
}
Catch(SqlException ex)
 {

 }
```

Comment: Thanks hey really appreciate it and its working just the way i want it! :-)

Comment: Is it also possible to make another page accessible once the user is already logged in?

Answer (score 0):

How about Forms autentication? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13872/Form-authentication-and-authorization-in-ASP-NET